# How to build enterprise ipa using xcode command line?

Tags: xcodebuild

Usually I use Xcode to build ipa file using enterprise build:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What's the equivalent of these using xcodebuild?

How to set the "exportOptions.plist", especially the key tag?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using Xcode 8.3 or above. Then the following should do the trick:

`xcodebuild -scheme <scheme> -exportArchive -archivePath <xcarchivepath> -exportPath <destinationpath> -exportOptionsPlist <plistpath>` with

- `<scheme>`: the name of the scheme you want to build and export
- `<xcarchivepath`: directory where any created archives will be placed, or the archive that should be exported
- `<destinationpath>`: destination for the product exported from an archive
- `<plistpath>`: path to the plist file that configures archive exporting (see content below, the teamID entry is optional)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
     <key>method</key>
     <string>enterprise</string>
  </dict>
  </plist>
  ```

You can get a list with all available keys for the plist file by running `xcodebuild -h` in Terminal.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Getting the error xcidebuild error: the flag -scheme cannot be specified along with -exportArchive

Comment: How to get the string for "teamID"?

Comment: The easiest way is to select your team on the project's `General` tab, then switch to the `Build Settings` tab and select the `Development Team` row in the `Signing`section. Press `⌘` + `C` and then `⌘` + `V` in a text editor. It should insert a key value pair with `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = xyz`